# Chaining three pandas statements

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to chain the following three statements together into one?

```
raw_df = df.copy().astype({'ids': 'str'})
raw_df['dels'] = np.where(raw_df['dels'] == 'nan', None, raw_df['dels'])
raw_df['langs'] = np.where(raw_df['langs'] == 'nan', None, raw_df['langs'])
```

If so, how could that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `assign` method to create new columns/overwrite existing columns. You can also shorten the logic here from `np.where` via `Series.mask` (or `Series.replace`) since all you want to do is swap our `'nan'` for `None` and keep the rest of the column untouched.

Without seeing a copy of your data, I can't be certain this will work but you can try:

```
new_df = (raw_df.copy()
          .astype({"ids": "str"})
          .assign(
              dels=lambda df: df["dels"].mask(df["dels"] == 'nan', None),
              langs=lambda df: df["langs"].mask(df["langs"] == 'nan', None))
         )
```

Alternatively, if you just want to go ahead and replace `'nan'` for `None` throughout the whole dataframe (and not just 2 columns) you can do it like this:

```
new_df = (raw_df.copy()
          .astype({"ids": "str"})
          .replace("nan", None))
```

Comment: thanks for this, why do you surround the statement with `(...)` ?

Comment: I surround the statement with parentheses because I find it nicer to read chained operations if each one is on its own line. You can also use backslashes ``\`` at the end of each line to achieve the same thing, but I find using parentheses to be more appealing since it avoids having a lot of backslashes in your code. Tom Augspurger (a core pandas developer) has a great [blog post on method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining) that I highly recommend to everyone.